Layout Issues on Mobile View - Header Cut Off, Text Overflows, and Newsletter Misalignmen
I'm working on a website, and it's displaying fine on desktop, but the mobile version looks weird. Here are the issues I'm facing (as shown in the screenshot below):

The header and navigation bar are cut off.
The text overflows outside the boxes.
The newsletter signup isn't aligned properly.



I've tried to adjust the header and nav parts to 100% of the viewport and also I've tried to add a margin-left to the newsletter sign up, but no luck!
This is my code:


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* To prevent horizontal scrolling */
}

header {
    background-color: #0047ab;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

nav input {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.post {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.newsletter {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.newsletter input[type="email"],
.newsletter input[type="submit"] {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mobile Layout Issue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Science Simplified</h1>
    <p>Exploring Science, One Post at a Time</p>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search...">
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Featured Article</h2>
    <div class="post">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
        <p>Some text that overflows...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="newsletter">
    <h2>Sign Up for Our Newsletter</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>




For proper view in mobile and tablets you have to make the website responsive. You have not written any media query in the css file. that's why the website is not responsive and the texts are overflowing and everything is a mess.
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 //write the css for mobile view here
}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width:998) {
 //write the css for tablet view here
}

You can add as many media query as you wish as per your need.

It’s not always necessary to use media queries in order to have a responsive website. For example, relative units can be used.

Besides that, it is far too broad for an answer but commentary at best. As Haworth already pointed out also technically incorrect. media queries are only a small part of RWD. There are even methods that can make layout changes without media queries such as CSS-Grid with auto-fit/auto-fill or Floexbox with flex-wrap.
